# Data Re-processing with specific starting point in Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am investigating data reprocessing with Kafka Streams. There is a nice tool available for data reprocessing with resetting the streaming application:  [Application Reset tool](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html).
But this tool usually resets the application state to zero and reprocesses everything again from scratch.

There are scenarios when we want to reprocess the data from a specific point, i.e.:

- Bug fix in the current application
- Updating the application with some additional processor and run with the same application ID

As in Flink also, we have [Savepoints](https://data-artisans.com/blog/turning-back-time-savepoints) concepts, which can restore the previous operator states and add the new operators without any error.

I also referred the following documents :
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Streams+Data+%28Re%29Processing+Scenarios
https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-reprocessing-with-kafka-streams-resetting-a-streams-application/

Would like to know :

1. Is there any checkpointing type of mechanism available in KStream?
2. How can we re-run the Kafka Streams application from  a specific point?
3. What happens if we change the code in one of the application instance and run with the old application ID?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Streams does not have a savepoint concept at this point (version 1.0).

1. Not at the moment (v1.0)
2. Yes. In next release this will be part of the reset tool directly. In 1.0, you can use `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh` to commit a start offset for you application (note, `application.id` == `group.id`). For older Kafka version, you could build a custom tool to commit start offsets
3. In general, it breaks. Thus, you need to use a new `application.id` (it's a know issue and will be fixed in future releases).

Comment: Does it refer to stateless and stateful operations? My understanding is stateless operation can be added with old App ID while Stateful operation will break it. Is it correct?

Comment: "In general" :) And it's not about adding stateless or stateful operators. One special case is, if your whole topology is stateless -- for this case, you can safely add stateless operators. For a stateful topology, it depends where you add the new operator... a stateful topology might break even if you add a stateless operator. There are many things to considers to reason about this -- it's hard to give a general answer.

Comment: Hi Matthias. You mentioned, "it's a known issue and will be fixed in future releases". Is there a ticket tracking the issue that I can follow?